# Looking for help to create a script for dynamic dropdown menu with condition if possible

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dynamic, drop-down-menu

am looking for help with this array formula to be done in a script to avoid the multiple generated rows that not needed for the dropdown menu

```
=ArrayFormula(if(C4:C="",,IFNA(if((D4:D<>"")*(F4:F<>"")*(H4:H<>"")=1,{"DONE","FOLLOW","DEFECTS"},{"DONE","DEFECTS"}))))
```

sample of the test sheet is here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JEO2vNxirY2NT2tRAnRNQpfY3hfyTuM1ppoUIil4Aeo/edit#gid=1382187552

the resolved or the above formula that FOLLOW will only show when D, F & H is not empty

also I was willing to add an extra condition the dropdown menu will not be active if A:A is Empty

looking forwards to your kind help.

Thanks,

Comment: Here's one: https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/multiple-dependent-drop-downs

Comment: Hi MetaMan,
appreciate your advice, i tried to readjust the sample unfortunately was not work, looking forwards to your kind help